What is the name of this widget used in customtkinter
I am looking for a specific widget in CustomTkinter. However, I'm unable to find it's name and how to use it to make GUI. Please help me identify this widgets


The widgets contained in the scrollable frame here are just frame that contain a button and a label.
You can see their creation in the add_item function:
def add_item(self, name, icon):
        """ add new package to the list """
        self.item_frame[name] = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.scrollable_frame)
        self.item_frame[name].pack(expand=True, fill="x", padx=5, pady=5)

        if icon == "tk":
            icon = self.tkimage
        elif icon == "ctk":
            icon = self.ctkimage
        elif icon == "pkg":
            icon = self.packageimage
        else:
            icon = None

        self.item_frame[name].columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        item_name = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.item_frame[name], fg_color="transparent", image=icon,
                                            text_color=customtkinter.ThemeManager.theme["CTkLabel"]["text_color"],
                                            height=50, anchor="w", font=(self.font, 15, "bold"), width=500,
                                            text=name, hover=False,
                                            command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.open_info_window, args=(name,),
                                                                             daemon=True).start())
        item_name.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", pady=5, padx=5)

        if self.data[name]["name"] in self.modules:
            version = pkg_resources.get_distribution(self.data[name]["name"]).version
            desc = f"{self.data[name]['desc']} \nversion: {version}"
            self.data[name]["installation"] = f"{self.data[name]['installation']} --upgrade"
        else:
            self.item_frame[name].configure(fg_color="grey20")
            desc = f"{self.data[name]['desc']} "

        item_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.item_frame[name], width=250, justify="left", text=desc, anchor="w",
                                            wraplength=250)
        item_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5)

If you want to use these widgets, I think you should not copy their code and just create your own because it might not be optimised for your project.
Hope I helped you, have a nice day.

It may be a button with hover disabled. I was making something like this earlier.
If you are referring to the names written in the boxes, like CTkMessageBox, CTkTable, CTkTooltip etcetera, they are made by a user Akascape on Github, StackOverflow. To use those widgets, download their source code and paste the folder into the same folder where you are coding.
